# How do I find out which databases are available in IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, indexeddb

I'm writing a cross/browser javascript "database explorer" that will allow me to look into local storage mechanisms.  This should be a pretty handy tool for development.  (Yes I'm aware that each browser has their own developer tools, but I want to create one that works across all browsers)

The question then is: how do I get a list of the databases that have been created in IndexedDB?  And once I get that list, how can I open them without causing a change in version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately simple: it isn't possible. And for privacy reasons it is a good thing that it isn't possible. The best way to make your database explorer is letting the developers pass the database name. I have written an indexeddbviewer my self, and I let the developer pass the db name in a data attribute. [A blogpost](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/11/indexeddbviewer-take-look-inside-your.html) shows you how you can use it, and the viewer is available on [codeplex](http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com/releases). And as last, I also have a [demo](http://users.telenet.be/kristofdegrave/Viewer/) of it.

Comment: Like Kristof said, there is no cross-browser way to do this. Chrome supports IndexedDB.webkitGetDatabaseNames(), opera will offer a similar function, but firefox will not. I do not know about IE.